# Ruby class with a module mixin

Tags: ruby, oop

I am trying to extend a module method in a class for a mixin.

Here is my code:

```
module Mod_1
    def bar
        puts "xxx"
    end
end

class Class_A
    include Mod_1
    def bar
        super
        puts "yyy"
     end
end

test = Class_A.new
test.bar
```

The best way of doing I could think of is:

```
module Mod_1
    def Mod_1.foo
        puts "aaa"
    end
end

class Class_A
    include Mod_1
    def foo
        Mod_1.foo
        puts "bbb"
     end
end

test = Class_A.new
test.foo
```

Is there a better way I can do this?

Comment: Is there a problem with your code? If yes, what is it? If not, what's the question?

Comment: The question is is there a better way i can do what i am trying to do.

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to do? And why this way is not good enough for you?

Comment: You can extend a module, but you cannot extend a module method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below:

```
module Bar
    def foo
        puts "first"
    end
end

class Class_A
    include Bar
    alias old_foo foo
    def foo
        old_foo
        puts "second"
    end
end

Class_A.new.bar
```

Returning:

```
"first"
"second"
```

This uses aliasing. I would recommend looking them up for Ruby specially for something like what you are trying to do.

Have a read of:
http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/aliasing.html

Comment: His first snippet works the same way (with `super`). Tried on 1.9.3

Comment: thanks that code works. Will try with 'super' too.

Comment: only that you need change `Class_A.new.bar` to `Class_A.new.foo`

Comment: Using `super` when possible should be *strongly* preferred before aliasing/renaming methods as it follows the proper inheritance chain and doesn't sidestep it. If you alias things around, you will have a bad time actually finding the methods that get called if something goes wrong.

Comment: i see, will be sure to remember that from now on